# Access controller level variable from action method attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, actionfilterattribute

I have the following base class for all controllers-

```
public abstract class BaseController:Controller
{
    public string BaseUrl
    {
        get { return "something"; }
    }
}
```

I also have the following action filter attribute-

```
public class CheckQueryStringAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    string baseUrl;

    public CheckQueryStringAttribute(string BaseUrl)
    {
        baseUrl = BaseUrl;
    }
}
```

I would like to use BaseUrl from base controller into attribute as follows-

```
public class LoginController : BaseController
{
    [CheckQueryString(BaseUrl)]
    public ActionResult LoginSuccess()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't pass a variable or object reference in attribute constructor parameter because attributes will resolve at compile time so you can only pass constant by their constructor.

But if you exactly explain what you want to do may i can solve your problem in other way.

Comment: I need to pass a variable in attribute. That's the problem.

Comment: its impossible. as I said attribute will be resolved at compile time. they used for adding metadata. so its impossible to pass a variable in attribute